# Convert multiple NOT IN to LEFT JOIN to improve performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query that takes very very long to execute.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.products_id, 
                p.products_group, 
                p.products_quantity, 
                p.products_length, 
                p.products_price, 
                p.products_height, 
                p.products_width, 
                p.products_weight, 
                p.products_cost, 
                p.products_rmb_cost, 
                p.products_best_rmb, 
                p.products_status, 
                p.products_image, 
                p.products_vendor_code, 
                p.products_date_added, 
                pd.products_name 
FROM   products p, 
       products_description pd 
WHERE  p.products_id = pd.products_id 
       AND p.products_id NOT IN(SELECT related_products_id 
                                FROM   products_related 
                                WHERE  products_id = '93667') 
       AND p.products_id NOT IN(SELECT products_id 
                                FROM   products_related 
                                WHERE  related_products_id = '93667') 
       AND p.products_group = '300' 
       AND language_id = 1 
       AND ( ( ( pd.products_name LIKE '%emerald%' ) 
                OR p.products_image LIKE '%emerald%' 
                OR p.products_id LIKE '%emerald%' ) 
             AND ( ( pd.products_name LIKE '%square%' ) 
                    OR p.products_image LIKE '%square%' 
                    OR p.products_id LIKE '%square%' ) ) 
       AND pd.products_id != '93667' 
ORDER  BY p.products_group, 
          p.products_quantity, 
          p.products_id
```

I was trying to convert the 2 NOT IN parts to LEFT JOINs instead to improve the performance, but I although the performance indeed improved drastically, the results I am getting are not the same as the original query.
Any suggestions on how to modify this query correctly to use LEFT JOIN instead of the NOT IN?

**EDIT:**

This is what I tried, but get wrong results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.products_id, 
                p.products_group, 
                p.products_quantity, 
                p.products_length, 
                p.products_price, 
                p.products_height, 
                p.products_width, 
                p.products_weight, 
                p.products_cost, 
                p.products_rmb_cost, 
                p.products_best_rmb, 
                p.products_status, 
                p.products_image, 
                p.products_vendor_code, 
                p.products_date_added, 
                pd.products_name 
FROM   products p, 
       products_description pd 
       LEFT JOIN products_related pr 
              ON pr.products_id = '93667' 
                 AND pr.related_products_id = '93667' 
WHERE  p.products_id = pd.products_id 
       AND pr.products_id IS NULL 
       AND pr.related_products_id IS NULL 
       AND p.products_group = '300' 
       AND language_id = 1 
       AND ( ( ( pd.products_name LIKE '%emerald%' ) 
                OR p.products_image LIKE '%emerald%' 
                OR p.products_id LIKE '%emerald%' ) 
             AND ( ( pd.products_name LIKE '%square%' ) 
                    OR p.products_image LIKE '%square%' 
                    OR p.products_id LIKE '%square%' ) ) 
       AND pd.products_id != '93667' 
ORDER  BY p.products_group, 
          p.products_quantity, 
          p.products_id
```

Comment: if product id can be 'emerald' then I've a feeling you've lost before you've even got started

Comment: @Strawberry lol... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below converted query to left join-

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.products_id, 
                p.products_group, 
                p.products_quantity, 
                p.products_length, 
                p.products_price, 
                p.products_height, 
                p.products_width, 
                p.products_weight, 
                p.products_cost, 
                p.products_rmb_cost, 
                p.products_best_rmb, 
                p.products_status, 
                p.products_image, 
                p.products_vendor_code, 
                p.products_date_added, 
                pd.products_name 
FROM   products p  
JOIN products_description pd ON p.products_id = pd.products_id 
LEFT JOIN products_related pr1 ON p.products_id=pr1.related_products_id AND pr1.products_id = '93667'
LEFT JOIN products_related pr2 ON p.products_id=pr2.products_id AND pr2.related_products_id = '93667'
WHERE  p.products_group = '300' 
       AND language_id = 1 
       AND ( ( ( pd.products_name LIKE '%emerald%' ) 
                OR p.products_image LIKE '%emerald%' 
                OR p.products_id LIKE '%emerald%' ) 
             AND ( ( pd.products_name LIKE '%square%' ) 
                    OR p.products_image LIKE '%square%' 
                    OR p.products_id LIKE '%square%' ) ) 
       AND pd.products_id != '93667' 
       AND pr1.related_products_id IS NULL 
       AND pr2.products_id IS NULL 
ORDER  BY p.products_group, 
          p.products_quantity, 
          p.products_id
```

Comment: aliases were missing in your original query, so may be conflict as we are joining with a new table called products_related if this table also contains same column like language_id, so if you get any such type error then apply aliases with it like p.language_id.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you!! :)